# Saving Camera Picture to Camera Roll in Flutter

Tags: flutter

````
    final testDir =
        await Directory('${extDir.path}/test').create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '${testDir.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg';
    await pictureController.takePicture(filePath);


    final file = File(filePath);
    print("==> hastakePhoto : ${file.exists()} | path : $filePath");
    final img = imgUtils.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
    print("==> img.width : ${img?.width} | img.height : ${img?.height}");
    print("----------------------------------");```





I am using Camerawesome package to take a picture, image were successfully taken but it isnt saved in the device. Any ideas please? All permissions were granted
````

Comment: Have you try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

Comment: did you add android permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ? also make sure your minSdkVersion is 21

Comment: Yes I did @FatihaIMOUSSAINE

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Solutions to your problem.

**First method:**

You can use one of the many available packages:
This would be an example integration for gallery saver https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

```
final testDir = await Directory('${extDir.path}/test').create(recursive: true);
final String filePath = '${testDir.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg';
await pictureController.takePicture(filePath);


final file = File(filePath);
print("==> hastakePhoto : ${file.exists()} | path : $filePath");
final img = imgUtils.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
print("==> img.width : ${img?.width} | img.height : ${img?.height}");
print("----------------------------------");

//Gallery saver code
await GallerySaver.saveImage(filePath);
```

**Second Method:**

Using Path Provider https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html

```
final String path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().path;
await file.copy('$path/yourname.jpg');
```